# how to access context member in dart class?

Tags: flutter, dart

im trying to access a field(a build context) in my class and it says: `The instance member 'context' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression`
here is my class:

```
CustomMaterialTheme({
required final this.fontFamily,
required this.context});

final newTextTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(
    bodyColor: CustomTaavTheme.textColor,
    displayColor: CustomTaavTheme.textColor,
  );
```

Comment: Could you type a whole class?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're trying to do `required final this.fontFamily` which is obviously wrong, you should read this https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem with setting a global key to materialApp like this:

```
MaterialApp(
  key: ServiceChargeModuleUtils.materialKey,)
```

and access its context like this:

```
ServiceChargeModuleUtils.materialKey.currentContext!
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are not accessing `context` from inside your class, but from an initializer as the error message stated. In an initializer you have no access to `this`, because the instance is not created yet. To learn about initializers, look here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#initializer-list

You can do the assignment in the body of your constructor. But then you have to mark `newTextTheme` as `late`.